# unique record identifier based on combination of attribute values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model with several attributes `MyModel(attr_1:integer, attr_2:string, attr_3:integer, attr_4: float, …etc, uid: integer)`

I need to fill each record's `uid` field with unique value for each unique combination of `attr_1` and `attr_2` values

Then i could use this field to find all "semi-similar" records based on this combination with trivial select

First idea was:

```
"#{attr_1}_#{attr_2}".hash #=>produces long (unique?) integer
```

But i do not confident if it gives the value i need

Is it? Or can you propose a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can change the **uid type to String**, you can use following method. Other wise you will have to implement something like in **public key cryptography.**

If you need to find semi similar records using the unique key, it have to have two separable parts.

```
hash1 = Digest::MD5.new << 'attr1'
hash2 = Digest::MD5.new << 'attr2'
```

Then you can save uid as,

```
hash1[0..6] + "-" + hash2[0..6]
```

This will create 13 charactor string(6 + "-" + 6)

Then you can use it in a search.

**Ex:** If you want to search semi similars with attr1x use it in a find,

```
attr1xhash = Digest::MD5.new << 'attr1x'
attr1xhash = attr1xhash[0..6]
"like 'attr1x-%'"
```

for attr2x

```
attr2xhash = Digest::MD5.new << 'attr2x'
attr2xhash = attr2xhash[0..6]
"like '%-attr2x'"
```

**Note:** There is possibility of getting 2 equal strings for non equal attributes. You can minimize it by increasing the string size. (Here 6)

Answer (score 0):

You can try MD5 hash Algorithm

```
require 'digest/md5'
Digest::MD5.hexdigest("#{attr_1}_#{attr_2}")
```

Will create a unique hex identifier for unique attr1_attr2 combination.